# SSRS 2016 - multiple tablix on one report causes overlap when rendering

Tags: reporting-services, sql-server-2016, ssrs-tablix

I have inherited an SSRS report which had an existing tablix on it - I want to add a further tablix below to display data from another data set as the format is very slightly different - each tablix displays a different kind of sales for a certain customer.

I have added the second tablix and the report seems fine within the report designer renderer, but when I access it via MS Edge directly from the URL the first tablix overlaps the second and obscures it from view.

I have set a page break at the end of the first tablix, and at the start of the second, and again in the designer renderer it works fine and pages, but in MS Edge it overlaps across the page break. In Chrome it renders OK.

The issue I have is I am displaying this SSRS report in a Web Browser Control on an access for an it renders just like it does in MS Edge so it looks screwed up.

It is like the first tablix just runs over into page 2 rather than making the extra content of itself page 2, and the second tablix then on page 3. I don't even really need the pages as ideally it would all be one long report with a vertical scroll, but this overlap issue means I have been trying to force it to split.

Any other way I can stop the first tablix obliterating the second one?

Comment: Why not create a subreport!! ?

Comment: Should I create sub reports for each section (tablix) and then put them all into an "empty" report or keep the first tablix on the main report and then subsequent ones within sub reports?

Comment: yup you can keep first tablix on main report and other ones within subreports and add give its reference in main report.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem recently (I found your question while searching for an answer).  I didn't want to go to all the trouble of creating a sub report and eventually tracked down the cause of the issue for my case which may be the same as what you were experiencing.

The issue was that my first Tablix was setup with a height of `2.7cm`.  My second one's top was `2.66781cm`.  That caused both of them to overlap with each other when the report was rendered.  When I changed the top of the second Tablix to `2.7cm` the issue was resolved.